# RibbonX Editor Callbacks and Interaction

Tags: vba, callback, ribbonx

I have (quite basic) question about RibbonX callback functions.

I coded some macros with VBA packed in VBA modules and created a ribbon tab by using `Office RibbonX Editor`.

I created an XML with the editor like so...

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="maintab" label="My Macros">
                
                <group id="g_general" label="General">
                    <button
                        id="btn_toggle_confidential"
                        label="Toggle Confidential"
                        onAction="Toggle_Confidential_Text"
                        size="large"
                        imageMso="MailMergeUpdateLabels"
                        supertip="Toggles the visibility of the 'confidential' tag in the master and in the title layout." />
...
```

...for all functions that I want available in the ribbon, such as e.g. :

```
Sub Toggle_Confidential_Text()
    If Has_Confidential_Text() = False Then
        MsgBox "ATTENTION! There is no confidential tag in the slide master!"
        Exit Sub
    End If  
    ' etc...
End Sub
```

*Everything works fine and as expected!*

In the "callbacks viewer" of the ribbonX editor I see this:

```
'Callback for btn_toggle_confidential onAction
Sub Toggle_Confidential_Text(control As IRibbonControl)
End Sub
```

My question is:

1. How does this accurately connect the button to the function in my code module? Or is this just some simplified display of the "routing" that is done under the hood?
2. Is the `IRibbonControl` parameter automatically passed, even though my own subroutine declaration doesn't mention it?
3. Can I (or how can I) access the `IRibbonControl` parameter in my subroutine to interact with the ribbon element? Do I need to redesign my approach and wrap my subroutines or can I just access the parameter, because it's implicitly passed?

Comment: You should have `control As IRibbonControl` as a parameter in your `Toggle_Confidential_Text` method.

Comment: When you are referring to `IRibbonControl` parameter, what do you have in mind? The ribbon controls are not similar to the ones used in VBA. Even if they can be accessed, but in a different way.

Comment: @FaneDuru I think I don't understand what you mean... I was thinking about the function parameter that lets me access the ribbon control element calling the subroutine.

Comment: @TimWilliams But why does my "configuration" throw no error?

Comment: @LCsa: You cannot access any control parameter of a `Sub` if it does not have a parameter... What I wanted to say, was described in my answer. The normal callback `Sub` should have `control As IRibbonControl` as parameter. In such a case the control in discussion offers only three properties (`Context`, `ID` and `Tag`) and it cannot be used/accessed like a VBA control.

Answer (score 1):

1. It should not work as you say it working... If the callback `Sub` does not contain `control As IRibbonControl` it should return an errror: "*Wrong number of arguments or invalit property assignment*". At least, this was happening when I tried creating the callback `Sub` without `control As IRibbonControl` parameter.
2. For a button control, no parameter is automatically passed. If you make the recommended declaration you can use 'Contol.ID' to have the pressed button name. 'Label' in fact...
3. You can, but not only knowing the control label. Besides label, it also offers `Context` and `Tag`...

Comment: ad 1) What dark magic is happening here? I am a 100% sure that I have no `control As IRibbonControl` in my subroutine (living in a module inside the VBA editor of a `*.pptm` file). My code examples in the OP are copy&pasted (and shortened).

Comment: @LCsa: Did you write the code, or copied from somewhere else? 1. I did not used IRibbon customization for Outlook. It maybe behaves differently against Excel and Word, even if it would sound strange for me, too. 2. I asked about the code author in order to better check if another declaration exists in another module. I usually use `Sub MyTest(As  IRibbonControl)`, but then this `Sub` calls `MyTest_()`. Maybe, "Toggle_Confidential_Text" from XML file has its expected `Sub`, which (maybe) calls "T0ggle_Confidential_Text" (I replaced 'o' with '0'). Or maybe not. Like I said, I never test it in O.